# In Excel VBA, How to add automatic value in range

Tags: excel, vba

I have list of jobs in *Sheet1* and 5 employee names in *Sheet2*. When I run a macro it should automatically find out the count of jobs and it should divide jobs equally to all employees and should paste employees to that jobs.

Here is code below

```
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer

Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
x = Selection.Rows.Count
y = Application.RoundUp(x / 5, 0)
```

Here, how will I give y value in range?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Where do you want to output y? adding before and after data illustration would be great.

Comment: x=636 rows, y=roundup(636/5) = 128 jobs for each employee.So, Now automatically one employee name should appear for first 128 rows and second employee name should appear next 128 rows....till 5th employee

Comment: Ah I get it. You want it to appear next to the selection right?

Comment: Yes, Please correct me in this. If i want employees in V column thn first employee should appear in first 128 then can i use range(v1:Vy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok try this:

```
Sub test()
    Dim jRng As Range, nRng As Range
    Dim i As Long, x As Long, y As Long j As Long: j = 1

    With Sheet1 '~~> Change to suit
        '~~> Change the range address to suit
        Set jRng = .Range("A1", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))'~~> contains jobs
        Set nRng = .Range("C1", .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))'~~> contains names
        y = jrng.Rows.Count'~~> number of jobs
        '~~> number of jobs per name
        x = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(jRng.Rows.Count / nRng.Rows.Count, 0)
        For i = 1 To y Step x
            .Cells(i, "B").Resize(x) = nRng(j)
            j = j + 1
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

This is just base logic. You can adapt to suit your needs.
In this code, your jobs are listed in *Column A*  and the names in *Column C*.
Output is then populated in *Column B*.

**Note:** This only works if the number jobs are exactly divisible by the number of names.
You will have to specify how you want to divide the excess jobs and adjust the code accordingly.